# “Dictionarial” analysis

Tags: single-word-requests

A given sentence may be analyzed in many ways. For example, grammatical analysis, in principle, would analyze from grammatical point of view.

Suppose I am analyzing a word (a concept) and I start by its dictionary definition and analyze only in that regard. What would the word "grammatical" in the above sentence be replaced with in this case? I thought of "lexical analysis", but I think that is wrong.

**EDIT**

Example: Suppose the word in focus is *to reason* in some philosophical context. But before delving into philosophical points I want to discuss the dictionary definition (perhaps to point out that the dictionary definition is too confusing, or self-serving, or whatever). And suppose before the discussion I making a relevant sub-heading. ***** Analysis (What analysis?)

I think *literal analysis* is also wrong for the following reason: Suppose I am discussing the word *devil*:

> Literally the word *devil* means “distant” as in “distant from the
>   mercy of God ...”

Thus, when I say "literally" it suggests that the literal meaning is different from its general usage. But that's not the case in the above example.

Comment: You are probably looking for *semantic*.

Comment: 'Semantics' is the study of meaning (in logic as well as linguistics). It goes beyond the 'meaning of an individual word'. / Dictionaries have got a lot better at explaining the meanings/functions of highly polysemous words such as 'of', 'for' and 'to'. However, even the best of usage notes explaining why just (!) knowing the different senses of a word doesn't confer mastery of the language are far from comprehensive. // 'That's wicked', for example, needs context to be understood; this is now in the realm of _pragmatics_.

Comment: Why not *literal*?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. When you are doing this analysis of the dictionary, are you analyzing spelling, pronunciation, meanings, etymology, relatedness between words, idiomatic usage, some combination these, or what? You give a supposition for example's sake, but that's clearly just an example and so not indicative of the scope of what you're asking. If all of it, then your analysis is lexical, but since you exclude that term, then you must be referring to some particular aspect within lexical analysis you are homing in on but have failed to enlighten us to what that aspect is.

Comment: By the way, you can always use "dictionary" as a noun adjunct and simply call an analysis of the dictionary "dictionary analysis."

Answer (score 1):

Analysis of the meanings of words is a subdomain of semantics called:

> [lexical semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_semantics),

the study of individual words and their meanings. [Lexicography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicography), the creation of dictionaries, and [ontology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_(information_science)), the study of words, concepts, and their relations, are both subdomains of lexical semantics.

Comment: There's also the fact that *devil* does not literally mean "distant", whatever Blackened's "literally ... means" means.  It is derived ultimately from Greek *diabolos*, "slanderer", literally "thrower-across", i.e., someone who throws obstacles in your path or otherwise makes things difficult for you as by slandering you or accusing you.  *Satan* is derived from Hebrew for "adversary, enemy".